# Load URL with parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a simple formulary, and a button to clear the text input. I want to use the function erase() to load the URL with empty parameters. Using location.href doesn't work.

How could make the function work?

This code is in a file called 'page.php':

```
    <html>
<head>

<script>

function erase(){
    window.location.href = "page.php?firstname=&lastname=" // not working
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action='page.php' method='get'>

<table>

<?php

if(empty($_GET['firstname'])) echo "<tr><td>Firstname:</td><td><input type='text' name='firstname'></td></tr>";
else{
    echo "<tr><td>Firstname:</td><td>{$_GET['firstname']}";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='firstname' value={$_GET['firstname']}></td></tr>";
}

if(empty($_GET['lastname'])) echo "<tr><td>Lastname:</td><td><input type='text' name='lastname'></td></tr>";
else{
    echo "<tr><td>Lastname:</td><td>{$_GET['lastname']}";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='lastname' value={$_GET['lastname']}></td></tr>";
}


?>

<tr><td><input type='submit' value='Send'></td>
<td><button onclick='return erase()'>Erase</button></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `Using location.href doesn't work.`? It doesn't reload?

Comment: I directly copied and pasted your code into a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and it worked as expected.  Please check your console for any javascript errors

Comment: I am using Eclipse PDT and run it with Firefox and Firebug. There are no errors shown. Simply hit the Erase button and the page don't reload with empty parameters

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I have the answer. I post it here, if someone have a similar problem.

In Firefox, when you press a button, even though it is not a formulary button, Firefox invokes the form handler. The default handler is the page itself, so it reloads the page ignoring the Javascript code.

The simple solution is adding a 'return false' at the end of erase(). The good solution is adding a button ID and using:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("buttonID").onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault() // NECESARY IN FIREFOX TO AVOID EVENT HANDLER
        window.location.href= 'page.php?firstname=&lastname='
    }
}
```

It works fine. Maybe someone can provide a more detailed explanation.

Greetings!